# How to release fuel injectors from Volvo T5 engine?

Tags: volvo, fuel-injectors

How does one engage the release mechanism for the fuel injectors on a Volvo T5 engine? The spring clip doesn't seem to respond to any tugging so far and I don't want to break it.

Here's a side profile image of the installed fuel injector outlined in yellow
[image: side profile fuel injector]
And here's a top profile where you can observe the U shaped spring clip hugging around the side of the fuel injector facing the engine head. Two injectors are in view so you can see the right side of one and the left side of the other.
[image: top profile of fuel injector]

Answer (score 6):

The trick is not to pull on the spring clip but rather to depress it by pushing it into the fuel injector in order to clear the locking tabs which then permit the fuel injector to be pulled out of the intake manifold.

The gif below demonstrates the push mechanism, which is effectively done with a flat head screwdriver.

[image: releasing the fuel injector spring clip]

Focusing in on the clip itself you can observe one of the two hooks of the clip  advance to the right of the locking tabs

[image: side by side image]

If you happen to find a little clear gel like rectangular rubber gasket that mysteriously fell out its from the fuel injectors, don't lose it and be sure to put it back inside when you're done.

[image: fuel injector rubber gasket]

Comment: Very nice answer!